# Postgresql ERROR: must be superuser to create a base type

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am trying to create custom data type as below

```
CREATE TYPE _kitdatatype (
    INPUT = array_in,
    OUTPUT = array_out,
    RECEIVE = array_recv,
    SEND = array_send,
    ANALYZE = array_typanalyze,
    ALIGNMENT = 4,
    STORAGE = any,
    CATEGORY = A,
    ELEMENT = kitdatatype,
    DELIMITER = ',');
```

The database instance is deployed on AWS and I am connecting Postgres user but getting below error.

```
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: must be superuser to create a base type
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes as per postgresql docs you need to be superuser.

> To create a new base type, you must be a superuser. (This restriction is made because an erroneous type definition could confuse or even crash the server.)

To make superuser in aws run these commands

```
create role your_user with password 'your_password' login;   
CREATE ROLE   
grant rds_superuser to testuser;   
GRANT ROLE
```